# What's the opposite of free-form?

Tags: word-choice

I want a word that conveys the opposite of "free-form," as in "free-form answers." Is it "pre-selected"? An example sentence would be: "Let's change the response field from free-form to [pre-selected?] choices."

Comment: In most contexts like yours, the best alternative is probably ***Multiple Choice*** or ***Tick Boxes***. But it might depend on the *exact* context. (Input screen on a PC? Questionnaire being filled in by a pollster/market researcher on behalf of a respondent?)

Comment: One possibility is 'menu'. This indicates that a list (menu) of possible answers is provided and the user chooses the most appropriate.

Comment: Formatted, restricted format, structured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, I'd use "structured" as the opposite of free-form. This would imply that instead of being able to choose anything, that there are a set of structured choices to choose from.

Defined as:

adjective
1.
having and manifesting a clearly defined structure or organization.

Answer (score 1):

A **closed-ended** question.

> A closed-ended question is a question format that limits respondents with a list of answer
>   choices from which they must choose to answer the question. Commonly
>   these types of questions are in the form of multiple choices, either
>   with one answer or with check-all-that-apply, but also can be in scale
>   format, where respondent should decide to rate the situation in along
>   the scale continuum, similar to [Likert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale) questions.

*Source:[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-ended_question)*

Answer (score -1):

**Pre-defined**

Not sure what to say about the proposal -- seems self-explanatory.

Answer (score -3):

Multiple choice describes a certain testing form.

Comment: *Multiple choice* is not an "opposite" of free-form, however; it is one of any number of non-freeform question types, which also include true/false, fill-in-the-blank, ordering, drag-and-drop, and hotspot among others.

Comment: Disagree. If you tell a student to expect a multiple choice test he will not be surprised to find true/false, fill-in-the-blank and so forth.  It's shorthand for not a written test.  I don't accept structured in the context of the question.  "Students, please expect a structured test on Monday", would mean nothing here in the US and hands would go up.  I have never heard "Students, please expect a fill in the blanks test, or drag and drop test on Monday." I stand by the answer.  I’ve never heard free form test.  These are referred to as written here.

Comment: I am referring to types of *questions*. If an exam has only one kind of question, it is indeed referred to as a *true/false exam*, *short answer exam*, *essay exam*, and so on, or more often, an exam will have multiple parts or sections with the same type of question. But if a quiz consists of ten fill-in-the-blank question, no, you cannot call it a *multiple choice* quiz as there are no multiple choice questions.

Comment: Of course you can't.  My point is a test hybrid is usually referred to as a multiple choice test.  If not, it certainly is not enumerated by the professor.  And it would never be called structured.  A multiple choice test can encompass many things, particular or not.  Is it the "opposite" of free-form?  I guess it depends.  Everyone I know understands this usage.  And yes, you can refer to a drag and drop or whatever test as "multiple choice" even while it is not.  This is my experience in the class room.  Thank you for you comments.   I have not been persuaded but it appears group has.